# How to patch a library imported with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

My iOS app uses Cocoapods to manage libraries such as AFNetworking, SDWebImage etc.

One of this library happens to have a bug that's been fixed in the bleeding edge version but it has not been propagated to the cocoapods version yet. I'd like to make a patch for this library and be able to share it with my team. What's the recommended way to deal with this?

On a side note: I'd imagine it might come a time where a similar situation could happen where I will want to fork a library. It would be nice if I then had a way to merge my changes into new versions as the library gets updated. Could a similar workflow be used in that case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forking the library, applying your patch, and pointing to your fork in the Podfile would be your best option.

If the library contains the podspec:

```
pod '<library', :git => 'https://github.com/yourname/<library>.git'
```

If the library does not contain the podspec, you have to copy the podspec to a local path and adjust it:

```
pod '<library>', :podspec => 'local/path/to/<library>.podspec'
```

Comment: You can also specify local path for pods: `pod 'AFNetworking', :path => '~/Documents/AFNetworking'`, as seen [in docs](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#pod).

Comment: @RomanB. Thanks! this is interesting, also I should mention for anyone reading this that setting :path directly links to the file on that hard drive which is very nice for development.

Comment: I feel like @RomanB 's answer is the best ! You should make that a comment so people can upvote it ;)

Answer (score 22):

I won't claim that this is the best option but it is one option.  You can use the post install hook in the Podfile to execute the patch command.  I've done it by placing the following at the bottom of my Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
    puts 'Patching SVGKit to compile with the ios 7 SDK'
    %x(patch Pods/path/to/file.m < localpods/patches/fix.patch)
end
```

Note that if you have any spaces in your path you'll need to escape the backslash that is escaping the space for the shell. "\ " instead of "\ ".  See http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html for a quick way to generate a patch.  Because I was working with 1 simple file I only created a simple diff instead of a unified one.

Comment: This won't work on second `pod install`, as it would try to apply the patch to already patched file.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. fork the lib and pointing to your fork in the Podspec as mentioned by Marcel - which has the downside that you have to maintain it against the upstream.
2. generate a diff file, based on your modified source against an unmodified version of the pod similar as was mentioned above by Sam.
3. Use this CocoaPods plugin that makes the process of #2 easier. See https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/cocoapods-patch

Answer (score 0):

Following Sam Corder's response, what worked for me was to `git diff` then add Sam's patch script in the Podfile

```
git diff branch-1 branch-2 > patches/fix.patch
```

```
post_install do |installer|
    puts 'Patching SVGKit to compile with the ios 7 SDK'
    %x(patch Pods/path/to/file.m -N < patches/fix.patch)
end
```

Note that by adding the `-N` or `--forward` option the `pod install` will not hang in the subsequent installs, it will just skip the patch if already applied.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html